# Excel 2007 in the Cloud

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, cloud

I need to find a way to allow users without Excel 2007 to interact with my spreadsheet.  The file has some complex macros and VBA code, so it has to be Excel 2007/2010.

The users are offsite.  Ideally, I want to send them a URL that links them to the spreadsheet.  From there they can view, enter data, and interact with the spreadsheet.

**Clarification**:
One solution would be to set up an Amazon EC2 instance with Windows Server, and install Excel on that, along with my Excel file.  I could provide a user with the RDP information.  They could then could log in and run the Excel file.  Are there any better solutions?

Comment: What does 'the cloud' have to do with your request?

Comment: I think by "Cloud" he means server based solution.  "Cloud" is the way the hip new kids speak these days.  Back in my day we didn't have clouds .. But I did have a onion tied to my belt which was the style back then

Comment: @Peter M: Perhaps, but I didn't want to make assumiptions on age, or requirments based on broad hype-speak. I probably just should have said "Please define your 'cloud'".  "And we called nickles bees". :)

Comment: Just keep in mind that, unfortunately, if you go your EC2 or similar route, you'll need an Excel license for each 'concurrent' user. To enforce this, non-volume license MS Office (OEM or retail, for example) won't install on a server with Terminal Services (RDS) enabled.  It should install and work with RDS disabled, using just the standard '2 admin account' RDP. Hopefully that will help more than my now-deleted answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to utilizing SharePoint?  I haven't used SharePoint super extensively but in my test runs with several projects, I've been able to successfully share Excel documents.  Users check out/in documents and can edit the information.  SharePoint also integrates nicely in a Windows Domain environment as well.

I'm not sure how you are setup, if you could deploy a SharePoint site from your network and your users may be able to access it via Internet.

There are quite a few ways to go about it.

Comment: That won't help users who don't have Excel, although it may be a great way to deliver content to those that do.

Comment: This was my error - I totally overlooked the part about users WITHOUT Excel... Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Executing complex Excel macros / VBA code without having a licensed copy of the proper version of MS Excel exceeds the proprietary nature of MS Office.  Possible alternatives include:

- Citrix (or similar solutions) which require multiple expensive licenses
- Rewrite using OpenOffice, and suggest all users install OpenOffice
- Rewrite it as a web or portal application, so users only require a browser